# Работа с датой в Android

Tags: java, android

Как спарсить дату из формата дд.мм.гггг, добавить к ней определенное число дней и разложить получившуюся дату на день, месяц и год?

Большое количество классов работы с датами, а также большое количество устаревших методов вводят в заблуждение и непонимание. Как я могу решить мою задачу? Минимальная версия API в проекте - 19.

Comment: https://www.joda.org/joda-time/

Comment: @StrangerintheQ неужто, чтобы поработать с датой в Джаве, необходимо использовать сторонние библиотеки?

Comment: Есть встроенный SimpleDateFormat, но с ним будет сложнее делать некоторые преобразование

Comment: Для манипуляций с датой есть такой замечательный класс. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно при помощи встроенного `SimpleDateFormat`

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse("31.01.1983");
Date newDate = new Date(date.getTime() + TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(2));
String formattedDate = formatter.format(newDate);
System.out.println("formattedDate = " + formattedDate);
```

выведет

> formattedDate = 02.02.1983